# Controlar tempo para retornar o timeout

Tags: c#, dapper, asp.net-core

Vejam o cenário:

Tenho uma `procedure` que executando direto pelo *SQL* demora cerca de 50s pra retornar os dados. Porém quando essa mesma procedure é executada via sistema, da *timeout* em 15s.

Minha pergunta é, seria possível limitar o tempo entre a conexão com o banco, execução da `procedure` e o retorno da mesma, assim, se for para realmente dar timeout, só apenas depois do tempo parametrizado e/ou aguardar a `procedure` retornar os dados?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
using (var c = SqlConnection(connstring))
{
    c.Open();
    var p = new DynamicParameters();

    c.Execute("minhaprocdanada", p, commandTimeout: 60 /*segundos*/, 
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}
```

Fonte: [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31995985/4649737)